# Changing the delimiter from ? to # for Cross Domain Tracking

Tags: google-analytics

Trying to do cross domain tracking of links to an commerce site (Volusion); currently produces an error because of the ? delimiter. I see I can

```
_gaq.push(['_setAllowAnchor', true]);
```

on the volusion cart site in order to enable seeing # as the delimiter instead.

I'm using the script provided by Luna Metrics xdomain.js which auto tags outgoing links for cross domain tracking. It’s not clear to me what to change in the [xdomain.js code](http://lunametrics.com/goalcopy/xdomain.js) to use # instead of ? as the delimiter, or can I make this default change with also using

```
_gaq.push(['_setAllowAnchor', true]);
```

on the referring domain where the outbound link is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `_gaq.push(['_setAllowAnchor', true])` and `_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true])` on both ends. In theory you just need them in the receiving end. But usually the receiving end can be both. User can be going from domain A to domain B or the other way around.

After that you'll need to modify the lunametrics script because it won't allow you to send cookies in the anchor as it is today. It has this feature hardcoded. These are the lines that you need to modify in the lunametrics script.

Find this line:

```
var fullUrl = tracker._getLinkerUrl(jQuery(link).attr('href'));
```

And modify to this:

```
var fullUrl = tracker._getLinkerUrl(jQuery(link).attr('href'), true);
```

Then find this line:

```
_gaq.push(['_link',jQuery(link).attr('href')]);
```

And modify to this:

```
_gaq.push(['_link',jQuery(link).attr('href'), true]);
```

Here are the reference on these functions:
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html

Comment: Great Eduardo, will try this. Separate question: does the `var domains` array need the source url included or just the urls of targeted cross-domains? Sorry, no docs on xdomain.js I can find.

Comment: Apologies for my earlier wrong answer -- when I looked at xdomain.js, I didn't notice that it didn't use the useHash parameter for _getLinkerUrl & _link. @eduardocereto's answer is correct.

Comment: @Conando you should include all your domains on the `var domains` Array. the lunametrics script is smart enough to don't include the cookies for links to the same domain you're at. After you fill in the `var domains` you can use the same script on all your domains. Which is nice.